# How to download and save a file from the internet using Scala?

Tags: scala, download

Basically I have a url/link to a text file online and I am trying to download it locally. For some reason, the text file that gets created/downloaded is blank. Open to any suggestions. Thanks!

```
    def downloadFile(token: String, fileToDownload: String) {

    val url = new URL("http://randomwebsite.com/docs?t=" + token + "&p=tsr%2F" + fileToDownload)
    val connection = url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
    val in: InputStream = connection.getInputStream
    val fileToDownloadAs = new java.io.File("src/test/resources/testingUpload1.txt")
    val out: OutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToDownloadAs))
    val byteArray = Stream.continually(in.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
    out.write(byteArray)
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flush the buffer and then close your output stream.

Answer (score 39):

I know this is an old question, but I just came across a really nice way of doing this :

```
import sys.process._
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File

def fileDownloader(url: String, filename: String) = {
    new URL(url) #> new File(filename) !!
}
```

Hope this helps. [Source](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-download-url-contents-to-string-file).

You can now simply use fileDownloader function to download the files.

```
fileDownloader("http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/resources/linguistic_utils/stop_words", "stop-words-en.txt")
```

Comment: what if I want to use the same code above and instead of downloading and storing it locally I want to store it in a different server whos IP is know to me

Comment: Thank you for adding the imports!

Comment: @Aamir depends on how the other server handles upload. In that case you'll the above mention method will not work.

Comment: Also when the file is not available there seems to be no way to catch the exception.

Comment: @user833970, you can always wrap the entire thing in `scala.util.Try`.

Comment: This doesn't follow redirects either :'(

Answer (score 11):

Here is a naive implementation by `scala.io.Source.fromURL` and `java.io.FileWriter`

```
def downloadFile(token: String, fileToDownload: String) {
  try {
    val src = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://randomwebsite.com/docs?t=" + token + "&p=tsr%2F" + fileToDownload)
    val out = new java.io.FileWriter("src/test/resources/testingUpload1.txt")
    out.write(src.mkString)
    out.close
  } catch {
    case e: java.io.IOException => "error occured"
  }
}
```

Your code works for me... There are other possibilities that make empty file.

Comment: Tried another link and it works, sigh, something wrong with the url I'm trying. thanks!

Comment: But what if the file is in a binary format, then I guess `src.mkString` might fail...

Answer (score 11):

Here is a safer alternative to `new URL(url) #> new File(filename) !!`:

```
val url = new URL(urlOfFileToDownload)

val connection = url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000)
connection.setReadTimeout(5000)
connection.connect()

if (connection.getResponseCode >= 400)
  println("error")
else
  url #> new File(fileName) !!
```

---

Two things:

- When downloading from an `URL` object, if an error (`404` for instance) is returned, then the `URL` object will throw a `FileNotFoundException`. And since this exception is generated from another thread (as `URL` happens to run on a separate thread), a simple `Try` or `try/catch` won't be able to catch the exception. Thus the **preliminary check for the response code**: `if (connection.getResponseCode >= 400)`.
- As a consequence of checking the response code, the connection might sometimes get stuck opened indefinitely for improper pages (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36426047/9297144)). This can be avoided by **setting a timeout on the connection**: `connection.setReadTimeout(5000)`.

Comment: Does the last line open a 2nd connection?