# How to configure SBT to let users download input data for my program from a public URL?

Tags: scala, sbt

I write a scala program that processes some wiki xml data. I want to get SBT to download not only  the libraries needed to run my program but also large xml data from wikipedia. How can I do this in my main program code or in the sbt build files? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For downloading it during the dependency resolution, I think you would need a custom SBT plugin. Doing it in the main program code is the recommended way.

To accomplish this on the main program, you could:

1. Look where the XML resources are? e.g.URL, auth tokens
2. Search how to save a file from URL in Scala. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162478/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-the-internet-using-scala).
3. Call a function that downloads the required files during application start-up, i.e. main(). You might also want to check if the file already exists to avoid re-downloading.